# How is it possible? see the below post it makes me confused

Tags: java

this Coffee class does not override method of the Demo interface. But it has a superclass which has a display method. My question is: how does this work?

```
public class Coffee extends Demo1 implements Demo {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Coffee c=new Coffee();
        c.display();
        Demo d=c;
        Demo1 d1=c;
        d.display();
        d1.display();
    }
 }


 interface Demo
 {
    public void display();
 }

 class Demo1 
 {
    public void display()
     {
        System.out.println("this is method in demo1");
     }

 }
```

output:

```
this is method in demo1
this is method in demo1
this is method in demo1
```

Comment: Hint: your question might get some downvotes because it's not appropriately formatted, tagged, or titled.

Comment: What's this got to do with a div tag?

Comment: What's so surprising about it? What else would it print out?

Comment: sorry guys i just have started here

Answer (score 1):

Your Coffee-object is a Demo-Object as well as a Demo1-Object, therefore the `Demo d=c;` is a valid statement, as well as `Demo1 d1=c;` . After that c, d and d1 all contain references to the same object and therefore will output the same string since you never defined any other functionality of `display()`.

Besides your code is really useless the correct way to do this would more likely be to let Demo1 implement Demo and then Coffee only extend Demo1. This way it would be more clearly what happens here.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I just have started SCJP and trying to clear my concepts.

Comment: Then maybe don´t start with polymorphism and interfaces, at most don´t mix both if you don´t know either of them. try to learn one at a time, maybe start with polymorphism/inheritance/"extends" and then if you understood that move on to interfaces. its quite useless to explain what happens in your code if you don´t know what you did there.